# How do I disable a button in a reactive form in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am working on a quiz app using Angular 10 framework. I would like to disable the next button until option for single-answer and options for multiple-answer questions are selected and then clicking on the next button should be enabled. When a user tries to click the next button without giving an answer, I would expect it to say "Please select an answer to continue." I tried disabling the next button by adding [disabled]="true" but it should probably be [disabled]="isAnswered".

Please could you see my code on Stackblitz: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-quiz-app**. I'm also enclosing a snippet of my button code below. I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Please could you help with this issue. Thank you!

code for next button (in quiz.component.html):

```
<div class="next-question-nav" *ngIf="question && questionIndex !== totalQuestions">
  <button type="button" mat-flat-button
    (click)="advanceToNextQuestion()"
    (window:keydown.ArrowRight)="advanceToNextQuestion()"
    (window:keydown.Enter)="advanceToNextQuestion()"
    matTooltip="Next Question &raquo;" matTooltipPosition="above" [disabled]="true">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 410.258 410.258">
      <polygon [attr.points]="paging.nextButtonPoints"/>
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: set isAnswered to true in selectedAnswer method and [disabled]='!isAnswered' and there may be problem with current flow you need to set isAnswered to false in advanceto nextquestion() and set isAnswered to true in previousQuestion() methods.With this you will be left with only one scenario where when you click previous question , you need to set again the isAnswered based on whether the question is answered or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a method `isAnswered()` to your component

```
  isAnswered(): boolean {
    return this.answers && this.answers.length > 0;
  }
```

and bind it to your button `disabled` property

`[disabled]="!isAnswered()"`

Comment: Yes thank you, that works!  I would like to leave a message if the user clicks on the next button without clicking on an answer, not sure how to do it. Also when I mouseover the next button the tooltip disappears.

Comment: One issue in one question, please open a new one for further questions.
Of course the tooltip disappears if your button is disabled.
Please accept and [vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) if your first issue is answered.